Apache SNI with redirection?
Lets say I have an Apache2 HTTPd with multiple virtual TLS-hosts for SNI.
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.mysite1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cer1
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key1
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/ca1
</Virtual Host>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.mysite2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cer2
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key2
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/ca2
</Virtual Host>

But now I do not want to host the site directly but forward/redirect to a local process.
How is that possible?
I thougt about ReverseProxy but as far I know that operates on the path and not on the hostname.
